# Values of padding bytes in C

Tags: c++, c, byte, padding

I've spotted a strange behavior in this small C program. I have 2 structures, both with padding bytes, but in different places.

The first structure has padding bytes with indices [1:3], and the output is expected: static variables are zeroed-out, so padding values are all 0, local variables on stack are left with garbage values in padding bytes. Example output:

```
Char is first, then int:
aa 60 8e ef ff ff ff ff 
aa 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff
```

But in the second structure, something strange happens. Padding bytes in this structure are with indices [5:7], so I expected some garbage values in non-static variable, but every time  the output is:

```
Int is first, then char:
ff ff ff ff aa 7f 00 00 
ff ff ff ff aa 00 00 00
```

Why the padding is always `7f 00 00`?

The complete program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stddef.h"

//  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
// |a|#|#|#|b|b|b|b|
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} S1;

//  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
// |a|a|a|a|b|#|#|#|
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t b;
} S2;

void print_bytes(void* mem, size_t num_bytes)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++)
        printf("%02x ", *((unsigned char*)mem + i));
    putc('\n', stdout);
}

int main()
{    
    S1 var1          = { .a = 0xAA, .b = 0xFFFFFFFF };
    static S1 var1_s = { .a = 0xAA, .b = 0xFFFFFFFF };

    printf("Char is first, then int:\n");
    print_bytes(&var1,   sizeof(S1));
    print_bytes(&var1_s, sizeof(S1));

    S2 var2          = { .a = 0xFFFFFFFF, .b = 0xAA };
    static S2 var2_s = { .a = 0xFFFFFFFF, .b = 0xAA };
    
    printf("\nInt is first, then char:\n");
    print_bytes(&var2,   sizeof(S2));
    print_bytes(&var2_s, sizeof(S2));
}
```

Comment: Your expectations are wrong, padding bytes always contain garbage. Even if this program shows that padding is always 7f 00 00 (or any other sequence) it does not mean that it is not some garbage value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no problem if I run your program. Last bytes are random. It likely depends on your system.

Comment: Yeah, should've checked the output on different systems before asking. Thanks!

Comment: That is not the point. Even if everyone on stackoverflow tried it and had the same value, it would still be garbage. As in: that garbage value could change next time you upgrade your compiler. Or it could be a side effect of x86 implementation that almost everyone would try it on. The point is: **trying it is pointless, because what matters is what the specification says, not what your specific compiler, with your specific options on your specific platform ends up doing right there right now**.

Comment: @spectras What I've tried to say is that this question wouldn't end up on stack overflow if I had at least checked output from different compilers. The very first online compiler already shows a different output.